# How to programme the position of the sun's formula in C

Tags: c

I've got this math formula which is used to find the position of the sun `d = 23.45p / 180 * sin ( 2p * ( 284 + n ) / 365 )` (where d - Declination of the sun, p-PI=3.14159 and n-Number of days)

I used the following coding in C to find what answer i'll get if I enter a any number of 'n', but it comes up with error when compiling.

The Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI=3.1415

main ()
{
       float a,b,c,d,n,answer,PI;
       //const float PI=3.1415;

       printf ("\nEnter today's number (between 1 and 365 days in a year)\n");
       printf ("to locate the sun's position:\n");

       scanf ("%f", &n);

       d = ((23.45*M_PI)/180.00)*sin(2.00*M_PI(284.00+&n)/365.00);

       printf ("\nDeclination = %f\n", d);
}
```

Comment: actually posting the error would be helpful also.

Comment: I'd also use a few more digits of pi.

Comment: Why are you using &n in the equation?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
#define PI=3.1415
```

turns this line:

```
float a,b,c,d,n,answer,PI;
```

into this:

```
float a,b,c,d,n,answer,3.1415;
```

... which is, most likely, the compile error (or at least one of them...).

Answer (score 1):

M_PI is an undefined variable. That's probably causing the error. Also, &n means address of n, so don't write (284.00 + &n). Instead just write (284.00 + n). Make sure you have included the right header file for the sin function. Also, as the other poster pointed out, don't define PI again.

Comment: Just been introduced to C programming and im trying to practice. Thanx CodeBlue. I've made the corrections you suggested and its working now

Answer (score 1):

I at least made it compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.1415
main ()
{
       float a,b,c,d,n,answer; // remove PI here.

       printf ("\nEnter today's number (between 1 and 365 days in a year)\n");
       printf ("to locate the sun's position:\n");

       scanf ("%f", &n);

       d = ((23.45*PI)/180.00)*sin(2.00*PI*(284.00+n)/365.00);

       printf ("\nDeclination = %f\n", d);
}
```

you can define PI as **#define** or as **float var**, but not both at the same time.

A **#define** don't need a **=**, it's not a assignment.

The **d=...** was not OK.

in **scanf** you take the address of your result variable (that is **&n**), but you simply use **n** in the calucaltion.

I have no clue if the results are OK, maybe you have some test data. (BTW: this year, 2012, has one day more...)

Comment: Thanks Jorg Beyer. Your corrections worked. Just been introduced to C programming and im trying to practice

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the & here

```
284.00+&n
```

You do the sum with just the value of n, you use &n in the scanf because scanf needs to update the value of n.

also use something like

```
#define PI 3.1413f
```

define does not need an =. If you have defined PI then you don't need to declare it

```
float a,b,c,d,n,answer,PI;
```

should be

```
 float a,b,c,d,n,answer;
```